# My If function won't be taken into account

Tags: excel, vba

The macro starts going through every cells from N19 to C14 (left to right). But when  it get to C19; problem is it goes to B14 which is out side the table.

I have tried including a few statements like End IF and thought of using the while function but seemed to complexify the problem.

```
Sub Testtask()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For j = -14 To 3  
        For i = 14 To 19 
            Cells(i, -j).Select
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

The image shows my working sheet and the table related to in the question:

[image: The image shows my working sheet and the table related to in the question]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this macro?

Comment: `For j = 14 to 3 Step -1`. And `Cells(i, j).Select`. Though you normally don't need to `Select`.

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) (As reference for what BigBen said)

Comment: @BigBen, that sure did do the trick. Thank you so much and to eveyone else  that helped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write code that reads like you would explain it:

> *[...] going through every cells from N19 to C14*

You want columns to go from N (14) to C (3), and for each column you want to go from 19 to 14. Since both loops are iterating backwards, the part you're missing in your `For` loop syntax (FWIW they're all *keywords*, not *functions*), is the optional `Step` specifier, which you'll want to specify as `-1`.

```
Dim currentColumn As Long
For currentColumn = 14 To 3 Step -1
    Dim currentRow As Long
    For currentRow = 19 To 14 Step -1
        Dim currentCell As Range
        Set currentCell = Sheet1.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn)
        'interact with the currentCell here
    Next
Next
```

Note that at a glance and without knowing what you're trying to achieve, there isn't really any reason to loop backwards: you could go `currentColumn = 3 To 14` and `currentRow = 14 To 19`, and the exact same cells would be iterated top-to-bottom, left-to-right. Code is easier to follow when things flow naturally: in general its best to avoid looping backwards unless you *have to*.

Also note the `Cells` member call is explicitly qualified with a `Worksheet` object (here `Sheet1` - your mileage may vary); if you really mean to work with *whatever sheet is currently active*, then you can use `ActiveSheet` as a qualifier and do `ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn)`.